# Can't use < in a sentence

Tags: html, syntax

I am creating an HTML email and one of the sentences uses `< ie <200 cp/ml`. However, this causes all sorts of issues and the rest of the sentence is broken up into words with `=` in between each word. How do I use `<` or `>` in a sentence in HTML without breaking the code?

Comment: use an html code &lt;

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the character by using `&lt;` instead of `<`. `<` is the starting character of an html element. The opposite side is `&gt;` (`>`).

Comment: Full list of the HTML entities here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: For most this will speak for itself, but I remember that I only figured this out a few months into learning HTML. `&lt;` stands for *less than*, `&gt;` stands for *greater than*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this characters for <  `&lt; or &#60;` opposite site > `&gt; or &#62;`

Comment: since your answer is the only one that gives both options my vote goes to you ;)

Comment: It might be useful to explain the difference between HTML entities and ASCII codes. If you are new to this, it is a confusing mess.

Answer (score 0):

> Reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities.

for `<` you have to use `&lt;` and for `>` you have to use `&gt;`

Reference

- [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: Wow, how fast are you guys! Thanks everyone, you've all been very helpful.